# ASP.NetCore 2.2 reading in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ASP.NetCore 2.2, VisualStudio 2019

I am trying to figure out how to convert a `web.config`file to `appsettings.json` and I am missing someting.

I have a `startup.cs` file that looks like (edited for brevity):

```
using System;
using MyCoolApp.Models.Commodities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MyCoolApp {
    public class Startup {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(
                options => { 
                    options.AutomaticAuthentication = false; 
                }
            );

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(
                CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2
            );

            var foo = Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommoditiesContext");
            services.AddDbContext<CommoditiesContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommoditiesContext")
                )
            );

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `var foo = Configuration.GetConnectionString(...)` line.

I have a `web.config` file that looked like (heavily edited):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CommoditiesContext" connectionString="Server=mydb.company.com;Initial Catalog=Things;Integrated Security=True;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient;" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I have turned this into the "top level" `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "connectionStrings": {
        "CommoditiesContext": "Server=mydb.company.com;Initial Catalog=Things;Integrated Security=True;providerName=System.Data.SqlClient;"
    }
}
```

I have an `appsettings.Development.json` file that looks like:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "path": ".",
        "inheritInChildApplications": "false",
        "system.webServer": {
            "handlers": [],
            "aspNetCore": {
                "processPath": "%LAUNCHER_PATH%",
                "arguments": "%LAUNCHER_ARGS%",
                "stdoutLogEnabled": "true",
                "stdoutLogFile": ".\\logs\\stdout",
                "hostingModel": "InProcess",
                "environmentVariables": [
                    {
                        "name": "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT",
                        "value": "44375"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT",
                        "value": "Development"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "COMPLUS_ForceENC",
                        "value": "1"
                    }
                ],
                "handlerSettings": [
                    {
                        "name": "debugFile",
                        "value": "aspnetcore-debug.log"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "debugLevel",
                        "value": "FILE,TRACE"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "modules": [],
            "isapiFilters": []
        }
    }
}
```

I have a `Production one as well but let's limit the noise for the moment.

My question, for now, is when I debug this locally I can set a bp on the `services.AddDbContext` line in `startup.cs` and then look at the value of `foo`.  It is `null`.  I have either structured the `appsettings.json` file incorrectly or am reading the config info incorrectly but I don't know which.

What am I missing?

**Edit**

`program.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace CalendarReservations {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseIIS()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, your `appsettings.Development.json` is completely useless. There's not a one-to-one correlation between web.config and appsettings.json. Stuff like `location` directives aren't applicable, and neither are sections like `system.webServer`. The JSON is just data, and the config provider will just turn all this into a flattened dictionary of key-value pairs, with keys like `location:system.webServer:aspNetCore:processPath`. That's it. Those won't actually have any effect. They're just static settings.

Comment: ugh, .NetCore is not my friend.  I dig that there is not a 1:1 correlation but it would be nice if there were a supplied conversion tool or better docs or something.

Comment: The problem with that is those are all IIS settings and ASP.NET Core doesn't require IIS so they are configured separately. `appsettings.json` et al are for the application configuration; not for the IIS configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the wrong base path for the configuration in the startup constructor. `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` will give you the wrong location and hence no config file will be loaded. Instead, consider using `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Take this out from your code (startup.cs)

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
```

---

EDIT: As Kirk Pointed in the comments

You need to replace it as such

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
```

---

why? Because if you have in your Program.cs class this

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
```

Then you dont need to set yourself

> Default configuration Web apps based on the ASP.NET Core dotnet new
>   templates call CreateDefaultBuilder when building a host.
>   CreateDefaultBuilder provides default configuration for the app in the
>   following order:
>
> The following applies to apps using the Web Host. For details on the
>   default configuration when using the Generic Host, see the latest
>   version of this topic.
>
> Host configuration is provided from: Environment variables prefixed
>   with ASPNETCORE_ (for example, ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT) using the
>   Environment Variables Configuration Provider. The prefix (ASPNETCORE_)
>   is stripped when the configuration key-value pairs are loaded.
>   Command-line arguments using the Command-line Configuration Provider.
>   App configuration is provided from: appsettings.json using the File
>   Configuration Provider. appsettings.{Environment}.json using the File
>   Configuration Provider. Secret Manager when the app runs in the
>   Development environment using the entry assembly. Environment
>   variables using the Environment Variables Configuration Provider.
>   Command-line arguments using the Command-line Configuration Provider.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: If I remove the section you suggest then I am in the same boat: `appsettings` is not being read.  If I leave that section in and add @DavidG's suggesting I do indeed see the connection string I am looking for.

Comment: You can't *just* remove the code mentioned; you also need to inject `IConfiguration` into your `Startup` and assign that to your `Configuration` property.